# ARC conversion tool issues: flagged retain/release, and random parse errors

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I'm revisiting an an older project and converting to ARC, my first time through Xcode's conversion tool (`Edit -> Refactor -> Convert to Objective-C ARC...`), and I'm seeing a couple things that I'm not sure are real issues or red herrings somehow.

I get, as expected a big list of things that the tool finds that prevent it from completing, but:

1. Many (all?) instances of retain/release/autorelease appear to be flagged as errors e.g. "release is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode". Am I really supposed to get rid of all these myself? I thought that's what the tool did.
2. In many of my classes, I'm seeing a bunch of errors that look like phantom parse/build errors that have nothing to do with ARC. E.g. in a simple class that apparently has no ARC-related issues, I'll get an "undeclared identifier" on some arbitrary method implementation, and then a bunch of "Parse error: expected }" at the end of the file, etc. These are not real-- the project builds fine, and I don't see any proximate cause or resolution for the errors.

There are "real" issues in the list as well (expected bridging issues that need to be explicitly clarified in code) but there are so many random errors of the above variety that it's hard to even find the signal in the noise. This seems wrong to me.

Am I misunderstanding what this tool is really doing? Apple's docs say this:

> Xcode provides a tool that automates the mechanical parts of the ARC
>   conversion (such as removing retain and release calls) and helps you
>   to fix issues the migrator can’t handle automatically

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a long time to resolve, but both of these issues seemed to stem from some custom macros I was using. I had a macro for release-and-set-to-nil that I was using frequently, like this:

```
#define RELEASENIL(x)   [(x) release]; \
                        (x) = nil;
```

I'm still not sure why, but for some reason, the ARC conversion tool didn't take this in stride, and choked on it, throwing the release warnings and the parse errors. (Some interaction with the preprocessor?) When I changed the macro to remove the release line, the conversion proceeded much more in line with my expectations.

And yes, it does of course remove the messages for you. (I'm answering my own question on the off chance that someone else ever has this issue.)

Answer (score 0):

1. The tool does not get rid of them for you, but simply adds retain/release code as need under the hood at the time of compile.
2. Those problems very well may go away when you get rid of old reference counting code.

**EDIT:** Further explanation:

> In Xcode 4.2, in addition to syntax checking as you type, the new
>   Apple LLVM compiler makes it possible to offload the burden of manual
>   memory management to the compiler, introspecting your code to decide
>   when to release objects. Apple’s documentation describes ARC as
>   follows:
>
> “Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) is a compiler-level feature that
>   simplifies the process of managing object lifetimes (memory
>   management) in Cocoa applications.”

In other words, ARC does not "strip" reference counting from your code, but rather does it on it's own under the hood.  You no longer have to type `release` or `retain` or `dealloc` again.  One thing the ARC needs to work is for it to do the reference counting *entirely* on it's own (with no user reference counting to "get in the way").

Comment: So what *does* the tool actually do, if not strip out the extraneous calls? Re #2, does this mean I should just ignore these errors while going through the conversion?

Comment: Updated my answer with further explanation.

Comment: This describes how ARC itself works at runtime. I'm looking for information on how the ARC refactor/conversion tool in Xcode works and what its output means.

Comment: The conversion tool does not (last time I used it) remove any code from your project, but instead simply enable the newer, ARC-enabled compiler. You must, on your own, remove old reference counting code.

Comment: Seems as though the tool is supposed to do this-- see quote from docs I added to the question. The question is why does it not seem to be doing that, or rather, why is it flagging those as issues I need to address?

Comment: The migration tool *absolutely* removes release/retain from your code.

Comment: The conversion tool is never perfect.  When I moved to ARC, I didn't use any conversion tool.  It'll be a PITA to covnert everything over, but it'll be worth it in the end.  You may have to address those peculiar issues, as ARC has some odd rules.

Comment: @StevenFisher When I made the migration, none of my retain/release/dealloc methods were rid of.

Comment: Again, that was my experience, and I cannot say it will be the same for you.  After I converted my most important projects, I never used the tool since.